# I want to convert json parent node and their child node into html in javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, object, dom, element

My json object format like
{"ops":[{"attributes":{"underline":true,"italic":true,"bold":true},"insert":"stackoverflow"},{"attributes":{"underline":true,"italic":true},"insert":" "},{"attributes":{"italic":true},"insert":"credit"},{"attributes":{"underline":true},"insert":"company"},{"insert":"\n"}]}

I have generated this JSON object dynamically.
I want to convert this object in dom elements.
bold,italic,underline all are html tags and "stackoverflow" is string .I have applied html tags on string "stackoverflow" and convert into JSON object.Again need to reconvert in dom elements using javascript.

Comment: Hi, please format your code to make it easier to read and explain more about what you are trying to get, what do you mean by convert it to html? If you check the preview of your post, you will see no html code there, im assuming its because you pasted the code but you didnt format it so please format the code with code fences to make the code visible

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What HTML tag do you want to create? e.g. div, span, input .....

Comment: Just loop through the `ops` array. Are you asking us how to write a `for` loop?

Comment: If you are able to do it then post your answer.